# Trying to flash CWM but fastboot hangs at "writing 'recovery'..."

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, clockworkmod-recovery, fastboot

I'm trying to flash my Coolpad 8865u (Vodafone Smart 4 Turbo). I unlocked fastboot
and fastboot oem device-info confirms this. However when I try to flash CWM the prompt on my shell hangs at "writing 'recovery'...". When I unplug and replug the USB to get it unstuck it stays "Failed (status read failed (No such device))".

However when I force a reboot it works fine.

Also I don't know if I'm doing this correctly but when I try to get into fastboot mode by pressing the power button and the +/- volume buttons the text "OFFICIAL" is displayed at the bottom of the screen and the phone vibrates but it does not get me into fastboot mode. It just reboots and keeps rebooting until I release the buttons.

Volume up and Power does get me into recovery mode though but there is no option to go to fastboot from there.

Finally I am also not sure what CWM image I should be using. I found a recovery.img on a portugese forum and they said it worked fine so that is what I am trying to use but I'm not sure if that is what should be used for the Coolpad 8865u.

BTW the whole point of this is that I'm trying to root my device. I don't know of any other way that works but would be open to suggestions. I already tried cyndia impactor and it says none of the bugs were found.

Comment: Did you try changing the USB port?

Comment: Yes, the sending works fine. It's the writing part that hangs.

Comment: Did you already pursue PIT file flashing to repartition? More hints here http://checkrom.com/threads/nand-write-start-stuck-in-odin.920/

Comment: My device is not bricked yet. I don't want to repartition because if flashing doesn't work afterwards it will be bricked.